# How to make a ListView from the Bundle?

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, bundle

My login activity needs LoginSuccess where my fragments are loaded there.
`LoginActivity.java`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,LoginSuccess.class);

Bundle bundle = new Bundle()
bundle.putString("first_name",jsonObject.getString("first_name"));
bundle.putString("last_name",jsonObject.getString("last_name"));
bundle.putString("username",jsonObject.getString("username"));
bundle.putString("email",jsonObject.getString("email"));
bundle.putString("mobile",jsonObject.getString("mobile"));
bundle.putString("appointments",jsonObject.getString("appointments"));

intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

How can I fetch the bundle "appointments" in a fragment? Thanks in advance.

`AppointmentsFragment.java`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle bundle = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_appointments, container, false);
    String [] datasource = {"appointments", bundle.getString("appointments")};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.rowlayout, R.id.txtitem, datasource);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    setRetainInstance(true);

    Log.d("appointments", bundle.getString("appointments"));
    View appointment_date = v.findViewById(R.id.appointment_date);
    ((TextView)appointment_date).setText(bundle.getString("appointment_date"));
    return v;
}
```

Here's the code for LoginSuccess.java

`public class LoginSuccess extends AppCompatActivity {
    Toolbar toolbar;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_success);
    toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new ProfileFragment(), "Profile");
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new AppointmentsFragment(), "Appointments");
    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}
```

}`

Comment: Can you provide example `appointments` String so we have something to work with?

Comment: You are starting an Activity. Where is your Fragment?

Comment: appointment_date":"2016-08-31","appointment_time":"19:00 - 20:00","pet_number":"2","appointment_category":"Pet Surgery","customer_name":"Manuel Velado","user_name":"mcveladojr","customer_email":"manuel.veladojr@gmail.com","appointment_status":"completed"},{"appointment_date":"2016-08-24","appointment_time":"08:00 - 09:00","pet_number":"2","appointment_category":"Pet Grooming","customer_name":"manuel velado","user_name":"mcveladojr","customer_email":"manuel.veladojr@gmail.com","appointment_status":"waiting for approval

Comment: You need to open a Fragment from your Activity so that you can get the "appointments" String, but I see you are opening another Activity here.

Comment: The `bundle.putString("appointments",jsonObject.getString("appointments"));` has an array value. And it shows like this on android. [Please check this](https://scontent-sit4-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t34.0-12/14193626_10211297513301912_585489081_n.png?oh=516f52ea7483e8426133da5152731d39&oe=57C7E8A6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First open the `Fragment` by doing this inside your `LoginActivity`

LoginActivity.class

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.example.vostro.myapplication.fragments.FragmentDemo;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_main);

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("first_name",jsonObject.getString("first_name"));
        bundle.putString("last_name",jsonObject.getString("last_name"));
        bundle.putString("username",jsonObject.getString("username"));
        bundle.putString("email",jsonObject.getString("email"));
        bundle.putString("mobile",jsonObject.getString("mobile"));
        bundle.putString("appointments",jsonObject.getString("appointments"));

        FragmentDemo fragment = new FragmentDemo();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.navigation_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }
}
```

Then inside your new Fragment get the data by doing this

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.vostro.myapplication.R;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class FragmentDemo extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_demo, null);

        String jsonArrayAppointments = getArguments().getString("appointments");

        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonArrayAppointments);
            for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                String yourRequiredField = jsonObject.getString("yourRequiredField");
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    }
}
```

login_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#2196F3"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/tv"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:textSize="20sp"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:text="@string/text"/>

    <!-- This will hold your Fragment -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: _I have error on:_ `fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);`

Comment: Inside your LoginActivity, you need to take on LinearLayout with that id which will hold the fragment.

Comment: @Haxor please check now, I have provided the xml file, in your Login xml just add one LinearLayout which will hold your fragment when you do replace action. Hope this helps !

Comment: _Im still trying it now, my web hosting is just slow. Thanks pooja for helping!_

Comment: Hi @pooja, the `R.id.fragment_container` was fixed when i added the `<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>` But the (R.id.fragment_container, **fragment**) shows an error and it says _Wrong argument type. Found 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment'_

Comment: Make sure that you import FragmentManager, FragmentTransaction and Fragment all are from android.app.FragmentManager, android.app.FragmentTransaction, android.app.Fragment Respectively

Comment: Guessing that this is your first time working with Fragments, please follow this link https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Creating-and-Using-Fragments to understand how to work with Fragments

Comment: Hmmm, they have been imported. `import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction; import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` The popup error says `in **FragmentTransaction** cannot be applied to (int, android.support.v4.app.Fragment)`

Comment: Thank you so much pooja!

Comment: @Haxor Please check now

Comment: Hi @pooja, I have error in `FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();` It says _Incompatible types_ **Required: android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction** **Found: android.app.FragmentTransaction**

Comment: It seems like I have two FragmentTransaction  imports but my imports are: `import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;`

Comment: Please remove the import with android.app.FragmentTransaction and make sure all the imports are from android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction
Please check my imports as given above in the example. All those are from android.support.v4.app.* package

Comment: Hi @pooja. How can is show the output in list view?

Comment: @Haxor Please follow this tutorial http://androidexample.com/Create_A_Simple_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=65&aaid=90 also there are many examples for how to implement listview

Comment: Hi @pooja. I have uploaded the `LoginSuccess.java`, how can i fetch the bundle there and load to fragments then show as listview? I already have the listview but I am having errors fetching the bundle to `LoginSuccess.java` and loading the fragment in listview.

Comment: Did you check Fragment.class shown above ? That is how you get the data in the Fragment, just add it in a List of type Appoitment class and add it your ListView

Answer (score 0):

While adding the fragment follow this

I hope you are adding the fragment in LoginSuccess Activity.So in that activity get the arguments like

```
Bundle args = getIntent().getExtras();
```

While instantiating a fragment, follow this

```
Fragment mainFragment = new MyFragment();
mainFragment.setArguments(args)
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_holder,mainFragment,"my_fragment").commit();
```

In your fragment get your arguments using `getArguments()` method

In your fragment use the following snippet to get the object of json.

```
Bundle args = getArguments();
String appointments = args.getString("appointments");

JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

try{
Object obj = parser.parse(appointments);
JSONArray array = (JSONArray)obj;
for(Object appointment : array)
{
appObject = (JSONObject) appointment;
/* for getting data here like appointment status use,*/
String status = appObject.get("appointment_status");
}
```

Comment: The `bundle.putString("appointments",jsonObject.getString("appointments"));` has an array value. And it shows like this on android. [Please check this](https://scontent-sit4-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t34.0-12/14193626_10211297513301912_585489081_n.png?oh=516f52ea7483e8426133da5152731d39&oe=57C7E8A6)

Comment: You could create a jsonobject to hold the appointments value. Make the object serializable and put it in bundle using putSerializable(Object ob)

Comment: Can you share your whole json using website jsonblob. This would help me in assisting you on creating a jsonObject.

Comment: _The array is:_  
appointment_date":"2016-08-31","appointment_time":"19:00 - 20:00","pet_number":"2","appointment_category":"Pet Surgery","customer_name":"Manuel Velado","user_name":"mcveladojr","customer_email":"manuel.ve‌​ladojr@gmail.com","a‌​ppointment_status":"‌​completed"},{"appoin‌​tment_date":"2016-08‌​-24","appointment_ti‌​me":"08:00 - 09:00","pet_number":"2","appointment_category":"Pet Grooming","customer_name":"manuel velado","user_name":"mcveladojr","customer_email":"manuel.ve‌​ladojr@gmail.com","a‌​ppointment_status":"‌​waiting for approval 

_how can i apply it on jsonblob?_

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sent data from activity to fragment then you have to use this code:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle()  
bundle.putString("first_name",jsonObject.getString("first_name"));
bundle.putString("last_name",jsonObject.getString("last_name"));
bundle.putString("username",jsonObject.getString("username"));
bundle.putString("email",jsonObject.getString("email"));
bundle.putString("mobile",jsonObject.getString("mobile"));
bundle.putString("appointments",jsonObject.getString("appointments"));

YourFragmentClass yfc = new YourFragmentClass();
yfc.setArguments(bundle);
```

Fetch value from onCreateView() method in your "YourFragmentClass" like this:

```
String strappointments = getArguments().getString("appointments");
```

Comment: The `bundle.putString("appointments",jsonObject.getString("appointments"));` has an array value. And it shows like this on android. [Please check this](https://scontent-sit4-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t34.0-12/14193626_10211297513301912_585489081_n.png?oh=516f52ea7483e8426133da5152731d39&oe=57C7E8A6)

Comment: print your array here. if your array like this "a","b","c" then split the string using "," then put each object in your array list . like this ----> String [] arr=strappointments.split(","); for(int i=0;i<arr.length();i++) String s=arr[i];

Comment: _The array is:_

` 
appointment_date":"2016-08-31","appointment_time":"19:00 - 20:00","pet_number":"2","appointment_category":"Pet Surgery","customer_name":"Manuel Velado","user_name":"mcveladojr","customer_email":"manuel.ve‌​ladojr@gmail.com","a‌​ppointment_status":"‌​completed"},{"appoin‌​tment_date":"2016-08‌​-24","appointment_ti‌​me":"08:00 - 09:00","pet_number":"2","appointment_category":"Pet Grooming","customer_name":"manuel velado","user_name":"mcveladojr","customer_email":"manuel.ve‌​ladojr@gmail.com","a‌​ppointment_status":"‌​waiting for approval`

Comment: first parse data , then send your ultimate result